# How I gain the Offer Eligibility criteria again when I have subscribed a product in Google play Subscriptions purchase?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am testing  Google play Subscriptions purchase  in Google Internal Testing channel with Android Studio, I have added my email account to License testers.

I have set Offer for new user (Never had this subscription) to purchase at discount price, you can see Image A.

It works well  when I subscribe the product for the first time.

The Subscriptions will be canceled automatically by Google when it reach to six times  Subscriptions by policy.

When I try to subscribe the product again, and I find the Offer is not shown for me.

How I gain the Offer Eligibility criteria again when I have subscribed a product  in Google play Subscriptions purchase in test environment?

**Image A**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen a way to clear test purchase history.

However, you can select the *developer-determined* criteria to purchase an offer as many times as needed.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that I can  purchase an offer as many times just like a user who never had this subscription in  `developer-determined criteria`  model ?

Comment: @HelloCW Exactly! That's the reason it's called *developer determined* – Google always returns this offer to the user, and the developer themselves decides whether to make this offer available for purchase or not

Comment: Thanks!   How can I set `developer-determined criteria`  to do that?

Comment: @HelloCW when you create an offer, you can choose it from a dropdown list

Comment: @HelloCW On your screenshot, it's labeled as 'Eligibility criteria'. You can't change it as the offer has already been created, but you can select the right one when creating a new offer